# Add required to input of hidden div when radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is to set hidden div with inputs depended on checked radio input.

This is the logic:

1. If the first radio is checked the first div is shown, there I want to add `hidden` inputs with some values...
2. If the second radio is checked I want the input to be added with required..
3. And, it shouldn't be required if the 2nd radio isn't checked...

I've tried a few things over some time and got some effects but can't get it work as I want, Here is the code that i'm currently trying to work with, sorry but it's messed up and fails...

So Any help will be much appreciated...

```js
/*
        // this code is working but I messed the HTML while trying to get it work with the other code below...
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $("div.hiddendiv").hide();
         check();
          
          $("input[name$='name02']").change(check);
           function check() {
            var test = $("input[name$='name02']:checked").val();
           $("div.hiddendiv").hide();
           $("#" + test).show();
           }
        }
        */

// The code i'm trying to work with...
$(function() {
  var radio = $("#closed");
  var hidden = $("#hide");
  hidden.hide();
  checkbox.change(function() {
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();
      //add required
      $('#name02').prop('required', true);
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
      //clear when hidden checked
      $("#name02").val("");
      //remove required
      $('#name02').prop('required', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="closed" value="01"> Closed
<input type="radio" id="open" value="02"> Open

<div name="01" class="hiddendiv">
  <input name="name01" type="hidden" value="code">
</div>
<div name="02" id="hide" class="hiddendiv">
  <input name="name02" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hba4d83k/),

Comment: do you have any jsfiddle?

Comment: your question is not clear at all. required on hidden input have no mean.And already first div hidden  filed have some value

Comment: @alive-to-die `required` is needed for the input only when related `radio` is `checked`. that's all what this question is about: how to submit when inputs are hidden and div not in use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

give same name of `radio button` so it will work as a group and

also set `id` of `input tag` as `name02` so its use as a `#name02` in jquery

so it will work

```js
$(function() {
  var radio = $("#closed");
  var hidden = $("#hide");
  hidden.hide();
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($('#closed').is(':checked')) {
      hidden.show();
      $('#name02').prop('required', true);
    } else {
      hidden.hide();
      //clear when hidden checked
      $("#name02").val("");
      //remove required
      $('#name02').prop('required', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name='btn' id="closed" value="01"> Closed
<input type="radio" name='btn' id="open" value="02"> Open

<div name="01" class="hiddendiv">
  <input name="name01" type="hidden" value="code">
</div>
<div name="02" id="hide" class="hiddendiv">
  <input name="name02" id="name02" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what I was looking to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you need to set the `name` attribute of your radio buttons to be the same value, otherwise the HTML won't know that they belong to the same group.

I've updated the JSfiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/hba4d83k/2/

What i have done is add a change event handler to your the radio group and then did some conditional logic to show/hide the relevant inputs.